# window.parent not found for refreshing parent tab

Tags: javascript

I need a button which

1. check some input fields
2. send form
3. refresh parent tab
4. close current tab

To do so I use preventDefault while clicking on the button, apply some checks on input fields, send the form, refresh parent tab and close current tab.

However, `window.parent.location.reload(true);`, reloads the current tab with the parent URL instead of refreshing the parent tab.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/parent

says this behavior means parent reference is missing.

Now how can it be missing if I opened the current tab with `window.open('someURL');`

I tried with `window.opener`,`window.top` without success.

I'm using Google Chrome 64.0.3282.186 (last stable).

I'm importing the following in the `<head>` for both tabs and javascript scripts are written at the end of the body :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js">
</script>
```

Code :

```
// form button in child's tab (javascript at the end of body)
<form>
    <button id="form-button"
            formaction="servlet" 
            formmethod="post">
            This Button Should Refresh Parent Tab And Close Current Tab
    </button>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#form-button").on("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById("form-button").form.submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        });
        window.parent.myParentTabMethod()
        window.parent.location.reload(true);
        window.close();
    }
</script>
// form button of the parent tab (this part seems to work fine)
<form>
    <button onclick="window.open('${ baseURL }/servlet?params')">
        MyButtonToMyChildTab
    </button>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        function myParentTabMethod() {
            localStorage.setItem("hasBeenRefreshed", 1);
            location.reload();  
        }
        if (localStorage.getItem("hasBeenRefreshed") == 1) {
            // some actions
            localStorage.setItem("hasBeenRefreshed", 0);
        }
    });
</script>
```

---

**EDIT : What I mean by PARENT TAB and CHILD TAB**

If you click on a link with the middle button of your mouse or with CTRL key in Chrome or Firefox, by default, it opens the link in a new "tab" at the right of your current page.
 The current page is the PARENT TAB and the new page is the CHILD TAB.

---

**EDIT 2 : Workaround**

I changed the scripts by the following to allow what I want, it is working, though without using `window.opener` successfully.

```
// parent tab script
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        function myParentTabMethod() {
            localStorage.setItem("hasBeenRefreshed", 1);
            location.reload();
        }
        var broadcastChannel = new BroadcastChannel('myChannel');
        broadcastChannel.onmessage = function (ev) { 
            myParentTabMethod();
        }
        if (localStorage.getItem("hasBeenRefreshed") == 1) {
            // some growl notification
            localStorage.setItem("hasBeenRefreshed", 0);
        }
    });
</script>
// child tab script
<script type="text/javascript">
    var broadcastChannel = new BroadcastChannel('myChannel');
    broadcastChannel.postMessage('whatever, parent tab just need to receive something to refresh');
    window.close();
</script>
```

Reference : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API

Comment: I think you need to clarify what you mean when you say "parent tab".

Comment: window.open, window.close - you have separate browser windows there.  window.parent does not work on a new window, you have to use [window.opener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener).

Comment: I tried with `window.opener.myParentMethod();` and `window.opener.document.location.reload(true);` or `window.opener.location.reload(true);` without success. The current window still refresh instead of parent window.

Comment: @Paul.F-G, what does `window.opener` return in the child tab? Does it return the url of the parent tab or something else?

Comment: Yes, in the child tab, `window.opener` has the `pathname` and `href` of the parent tab.

Comment: `myParentTabMethod` isn't available on the window - its scope is limited to document.ready.  You might try defining `window.myParentTabMethod = function ()...` instead.  I don't think that will fix your main problem, though.

Comment: I edited the post with a solution a the bottom.

Comment: BroadcastChannel is not working in Safari browser.

Comment: @Hieu Yes, use [sysend.js](https://github.com/jcubic/sysend.js/) in this case.